# Excel export chart to wmf or emf?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export a chart from Excel to either the wmf or emf format.

The code works if you export to GIF but not with WMF as the filtername.

This works:

```
Chart.Export FileName:="current_sales.gif", FilterName:="GIF"
```

But

```
Chart.Export FileName:="current_sales.wmf", FilterName:="WMF"
```

fails giving the error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined
>   error

Powerpoint allows you to export to WMF. And I have "successfully" exported by copying the graph into Powerpoint and having Powerpoint export the image to WMF but there has to be an easier way - I hope.

I wonder if there may be a way of registering the WMF filter for Excel but I am unsure how to do this. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Andronov - does it need to use the export command? Would another method that saves the chart in a different way be okay?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This copy, save method worked for me,** i put it into 3 sections (declarations, saves as EMF function, and the select/copy/function call section):

*I found [this article](http://www.xcelfiles.com/EMF_Save.html) detailing how to save to EMF then doctored it a bit to use the an ActiveChart instead of a arbitrary selection.

First off a couple declarations:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard _
    Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetClipboardData _
    Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal wFormat As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'// CreateMetaFileA DeleteEnhMetaFile
Private Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFileA _
    Lib "gdi32" ( _
        ByVal hENHSrc As Long, _
        ByVal lpszFile As String) _
As Long

Private Declare Function DeleteEnhMetaFile _
    Lib "gdi32" ( _
        ByVal hemf As Long) _
As Long
```

This is the actual save as emf function (the use of CopyEnhMetaFileA and DeleteEnhMetaFile are explained in the article):

```
Public Function fnSaveAsEMF(strFileName As String) As Boolean
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE As Long = 14

Dim ReturnValue As Long

    OpenClipboard 0

    ReturnValue = CopyEnhMetaFileA(GetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE), strFileName)

    EmptyClipboard

    CloseClipboard

    '// Release resources to it eg You can now delete it if required
    '// or write over it. This is a MUST
    DeleteEnhMetaFile ReturnValue

    fnSaveAsEMF = (ReturnValue <> 0)

End Function
```

Then the select, copy, and function call section:

```
Sub SaveIt()
Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    Selection.Copy
    If fnSaveAsEMF("C:\Excel001.emf") Then
        MsgBox "Saved", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "NOT Saved!", vbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I found your answer looks really promising, but I couldn't reproduce the export of charts in *.emf format. I get a not saved message without any further Idea why it refuse to work.

All I did was adding "PtrSafe" between ... declare Function. 

What did I forget?

Answer (score 1):

Through [this forum entry](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/569790-export-excel2000-charts-into-emf-wmf.html) you can find the marvelous [Stephen Bullen's Excel Page](http://www.bmsltd.co.uk/Excel/Default.htm) and download the [PastePicture utility](http://www.bmsltd.co.uk/DLCount/DLCount.asp?file=PastePicture.zip) which shows how you can export to the WMF format.

It basically copies the chart, pastes it into the clipboard as a picture and saves its content into a WMF file in a few lines of code.